# How to check the collection is exist using MongoJS and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I need to check if the collection is exist in the DB using Node.js and MongoDB. Here I am using mongoJS as node driver. My code is below:

```
var mongoJs=require('mongojs');
var md5 = require('md5');
var dateTime = require('node-datetime');
var collections=['f_users'];
var MONGOLAB_URI="mongodb://user:*****123%40@ds127153.mlab.com:27153/fgdp";
var db=mongoJs(MONGOLAB_URI,collections);
exports.userSignup=function(req,res){
    var email=req.body.email;
    var password=req.body.password;
    var dob=req.body.dob;
    var dt = dateTime.create();
    var createdDate=dt.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');
    var updateDate=dt.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');
    db.f_user_login
    db.f_user_login.insert()
}
```

Here I need if collection `f_user_login` exist inside db or not. If not exist it will insert the required document.

Comment: Why do you think you need to know if the "collection" exists? MongoDB generally does not care. It seems if all you really want to know is whether to insert a document or not, then you should be using ["upserts"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) to decide whether or not to create the 'document'. The "collection" will simply just be created as the "document" is written, or otherwise just exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you first need to add the collection to your db.

`var db=mongoJs(MONGOLAB_URI,['f_user_login', 'f_users']);`

And then you can try running this

```
var fUserLoginExist = db.f_user_login.findOne();
if (fUserLoginExist) {
  // the collection exists
} else {
  // the collection does not exist
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

When I wish to check an existence of collection, I use an easy piece of code below

```
  var nmColl = "MyCollection";
  if(db.getCollectionNames().find(function(el) {return el == nmColl;}) == null)
  {
     //do something
  }
```

It is good for MongoDB up 3.0. At first, there is function **db.getCollectionNames()** to return all exists collections, when I look up specified name of collection. If there is no necessary collection, for example, I will create it.